# Adding global scss Styles leads to extremely high Nitro warm-up times

Tags: sass, vite, nuxt3

**Update**

There is an Issue regarding this problem:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/23504

**Initial post:**

I am migrating a Nuxt 2 project to Nuxt 3. The old project used the library [style-resources-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module) to make SCSS Variables available everywhere.

Apparently Nuxt3 does not need this anymore, I can add my styles in the [Nuxt Config](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/styling#using-preprocessors) like this:

```
vite: {
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: `
                @import "@/assets/styles/utilities/_all.scss";
                @import "@/assets/styles/variables/_colors.scss";
                @import "@/assets/styles/bulma/utilities/_all.scss";
                @import "@/assets/styles/utilities/_functions.scss";
                `
            }
        }
    }
},
css: ['@/assets/styles/main.scss'],
```

main.scss in turn imports many other styles.

This works but now **nitro takes over 90 seconds to warm up (instead of 2 seconds)**.
I read about using **@use instead of @import**, but this leads to undefined scss variables.

Apparenty, I cannot simply replace it - why is that ? Did I miss something ?
How can I reduce this warm up time ?